# Why process is killed while a lot of memory is free?

Tags: memory, kill, virtual-memory

I am running a python script in ipython. This script will take about 8GB RAM. The system has more than 80 GB free RAM but the swap is nearly 0. My script was killed after it runned for a while. I want to know under which circumstances the system will kill such a big program with still a lot of free memory?

Comment: Killed by [OOM Killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)?  Then you might want to check cgroup settings (memory subsystem). If just received a signal like SIGSEGV, running with `strace` might help, but be prepared against significant overhead.  Also check `ulimit -a`.

Comment: Are you sure it was killed **due** **to** **an** **out** **of** **memory** **error**? Because maybe it shut down for some other reason.